# Pirated software screenshots in question; what is SE policy?

Tags: discussion, stackexchange, etiquette

Copyright is a delicate subject. SE has a strict policy regarding copy pasting other people's text. Correctly citing parts or rephrasing in your own words mitigates this.

What is SE policy for questions containing screenshots of pirated software? What should we do? It must be clear that such practices shouldn't be allowed or endorsed at `3DPrinting.SE`.

Comment: Is it obvious from the screenshot that the software is pirated? Is there a particular example that you have in mind?

Comment: Yes on both accounts, let's discuss in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/50148259#50148259)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this question, [Is it okay that questions mention illegal downloads?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208610/is-it-okay-that-questions-mention-illegal-downloads)

> It's none of our business, really, and more importantly, as you're proving right now, it's nothing but a distraction from the meat of the question. What would you have SE, Inc. do, anyways?
>
> The appropriate action is to edit that information out of the question, since it (almost certainly) has no bearing on the technical issue, which might also be faced by someone else who does not have a pirated copy.

The second answer to that question more or less states that if the user isn't asking how to download or hack, but just has a basic issue with the software, which *a licensed user would also encounter*, then it isn't a problem... apparently.